# Make child element in anchor non interactive

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a div wrap inside anchor tag. Inside that div is a button. This share button has a different interaction. I want every area in the div to interact with the href value except for the button. Just the same way the hover is different on the button compared to the div parent. Thanks for your help
https://play.tailwindcss.com/nPsNX1vseI

I was able to make the hover different for the parent and the share button. Trying similar effect can't seem to work for the share button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider not wrapping the card in an `<a>` element at all. Instead, have it as a child that links with meaningful text content of the UI element (for a11y purposes). Then have an absolutely-positioned element inside the link that expands out over the parent `<div>`. Then have the `<button>` be displayed over the absolutely-positioned element.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="w-[90%] flex-none snap-start rounded-md border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow-sm transition-shadow ease-in hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-600 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 md:w-[340px] relative">
  <div class="relative w-full">
    <img class="h-52 w-full rounded-t-md" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/24/10/47/house-1477041_960_720.jpg" />
    <div class="absolute top-0 h-full w-full">
      <div class="h-full rounded-t-md bg-gray-800/5 p-4 backdrop-brightness-75">
        <div class=" absolute bottom-1 flex w-full flex-row gap-2 -z-1">
          <div class="flex basis-3/4 items-end"></div>
          <div class="basis-1/4 ">
            <button class="rounded-full border bg-neutral p-1  hover:bg-green-500 dark:ring-gray-500 cursor-auto relative z-10" type="button">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 font-bold " aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M13 4.5a2.5 2.5 0 11.702 1.737L6.97 9.604a2.518 2.518 0 010 .792l6.733 3.367a2.5 2.5 0 11-.671 1.341l-6.733-3.367a2.5 2.5 0 110-3.475l6.733-3.366A2.52 2.52 0 0113 4.5z"></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://google.com">
    What is Lorem Ipsum?
    <span class="absolute inset-0"></span>
  </a>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. Makes alot of sense to stack the div with anchor.
Thanks